# javascript equivalent of join() and toString() in c#?

Tags: c#, string

is there any method in c# thats equivalent to the javascript **join()**..

```
   var keyStr = keyList.join("_");
```

My requirement is to concatenate the array of strings into an single string with the given separator.

And i wanted to convert my whole string array into an single string... in javascript we can do this by calling **toString()** of the jabvascript array

C# toString of an array just prints the type information. If we use toString on other types like int, it returns the string representation of an int. But why this is been not implemented in String array. wouldnt that strange??

And

Comment: The title should be "C# equivalent of JavaScript join() and toString()"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `string.Join()`:

```
string.Join("_", array);
```

or, for lists:

```
string.Join("_", list);
```

Converting a string array into a single string is done exactly the same way: With `string.Join()`:

```
string.Join(" ", stringarray);
```

[Dan Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443091/javascript-equivalent-of-join-and-tostring-in-c/1443119#1443119) also has a nice extension method you can use to be a little closer to JavaScript, syntax-wise.

Comment: thanks johannes. Join works perfectly, but my second requirement is to convert string array into an single string value...

Comment: @Ramesh you can either use String.Join("", stringArray) or String.Concat(stringArray)

Answer (score 3):

if you wish to add the functionality to a string array you could do with an extension method

```
public static class ArrayExtension
{

  public static string AsString(this string[] array, string seperator)
  {
    return string.Join(seperator, array);
  }
}
```

Then you would write:

```
var keyStr = keyList.AsString("_");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below.

```
 string[] arr=new string[]{"aa","bb","cc"};
 string.Join("-", arr);
```